# LLVM/Clang Error: Expected top-level entity

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang

I am trying to compile a FirmwareProject which has both C and C++ code using LLVM/Clang. But, I get the following error which I am not able to get rid of:

```
Description Resource        Path            Location    
expected top-level entity   Bx000484        line 1, external location: C:\Program Files (x86)\msys64\mingw64\bin\llvm-as.exe: obj\rel\LibStm32f10x\LibStm32f10x\src\cortexm3_macro.s.o.s
```

I tried trying the different LLVM compiler and linker flags. But nothing seems to work:

```
### Global complier and linker settings
INCLUDES_APP    := -I$(GLOBALS_DIR)/inc -I$(LIBGLOBALS_DIR)/inc -I$(LIBSTM32F10X_DIR)/inc
AFLAGS          :=
CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wstrict-prototypes -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -mlittle-endian -D_FLASH_PROG
CXXFLAGS := -Wall -Wnarrowing -Wextra -Wmissing-field-initializers -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fsigned-char -ffunction-sections -mlittle-endian -D_FLASH_PROG
LINKER_FILE := $(LD_DIR)/STM32F101_64K_10K_FLASH.ld
LFLAGS := --specs=rdimon.specs -Wl,--start-group -lgcc -lc -lm -lrdimon -Wl,--end-group \
        -mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb -Wl,-L$(LD_DIR) -Wl,-static -Wl,--gc-sections -nostartfiles --specs=nosys.specs -specs=nano.specs

### TOOLCHAIN
COMMAND_DIR     := "$(PROGRAMFILES)\msys64\mingw64\bin"
COMMAND_PREFIX  := arm-none-eabi-
CMD_PREFIX  := arm-none-eabi-
CC       := $(COMMAND_DIR)/clang
CPPC     := $(COMMAND_DIR)/clang++
ASM      := $(COMMAND_DIR)/llvm-as
LINK     := $(COMMAND_DIR)/clang++ 
ELFBIN   := $(COMMAND_DIR)/objcopy
AR       := $(COMMAND_DIR)/llvm-ar
SIZE     := $(COMMAND_DIR)/llvm-size
```

Answer (score 3):

`llvm-as` command assembles LLVM IR sources, not assembler ones. Try using `clang` as `ASM`, or `llvm-mc -assemble`.